# Sever integration of Aperture in iWork

Tags: macos, iwork, aperture

I'm using both Aperture and iWork (Numbers in particular). The thing is my aperture library is kind of big (about 1000 albums with 10 to 100 photos each) and I noticed that when I use Numbers, a lot of resources for the media library are being used by the process `com.apple.MediaLibraryService` in Activity Monitor.

The two activites I have with those two softwares are not related, thus I'd like to stop the integration of Aperture in Numbers (and why not the whole iWork suite) to be able to use it alone witout having it indexing (or whatever it does) my Aperture library.

The question is how?

Comment: Are you keying on the Media button at the top of a numbers document or the photos portion of the open / save dialog? (Or perhaps something else in terms of integration?)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by keying (not english speaking native). But even without opening the media library, I have a process named Media<Something> (not on my mac right now) taking high CPU and memory when Numbers is open.

Comment: Apologies for the key verb. When you get back to the Mac, consider editing in the process name that is using energy and CPU resources.

Comment: The exact name of the process is com.apple.MediaLibraryService